# open csv file from SFTP and extract file contents into php array

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, sftp

I need to access a .csv file that is newly uploaded to an sftp every night. I would like to be able to access the data within the .csv file and display it in an html table on a webpage.

Previously the .csv sat on our server at a public url. I used php within a wordpress page template to open file and parse into an array which allowed me to output the data onto our webpage:

```
<?php
    $filename = 'https://myoldfileurl.csv';
    $my_array = []; 
     if (($h = fopen("{$filename}", "r")) !== FALSE) 
    {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($h, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
        {
        $my_array[] = $data;   
                }
        fclose($h);
    }
?>
```

But now I need to get the .csv file from sftp instead of the public url as shown above. I am trying to accomplish the same thing. Access the file, open it and spit out its contents into an array that I can pull specific data points from. As mentioned, this is a wordpress site that I have developed locally. I added the SSH SFTP Updater Support plugin. Here is the code I have but I am not sure if this is the right way to go about it:

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('sftp.mysite.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

$stream = fopen('ssh2.sftp://' . intval($sftp) . '/Download/mydatafile.csv', 'r');
?>
```

When running the code I get the following error: **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect().....**

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the php-ssh2 package to your system to enable these functions.